# Off by one error in binary search (corner case)

Tags: python, algorithm

I'm having trouble with a corner case in my version of binary search. My version will output the bin which contains a 1 in the input list. The algorithm does this by testing groups of half the size of the input list respectively- upper and lower in the code below - and if the presence of a 1 is detected the algorithm moves the references around like a normal binary search and continues until it has found the 1. The list contains only 1s and 0s.

N.B. It has been pointed out to me that any() will scan the (sub)list with an O(n) operation, and so seemingly defeat the purpose of the algorithm below (which is to identify the position of a 1 by testing sub-lists). I am actively looking for a better test, and would be happy to hear any ideas, but I am (currently) actively interested in resolving this issue.

Below is the function:

```
def binary_search(inList):
    low = 0
    high = len(inList)

    while low < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        upper = inList[mid:high]
        lower = inList[low:mid]
        if any(lower):
            high = mid
        elif any(upper):
            low = mid+1
       else:
            # Neither side has a 1
            return -1
    return mid
```

Here are the unit tests the above code passes:

```
# Test a basic case
inlist = [0] * 256
inlist[123] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 123

# Test a case with odd len
inlist = [0] * 99
inlist[20] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 20

# Test a case with odd len
inlist = [0] * 100
inlist[20] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 20

inlist = [0]*4
inlist[1] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 1

# Start
inlist = [0] * 256
inlist[0] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 0

##middle
inlist = [0] * 256
inlist[128] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 128

#end
inlist = [0] * 256
inlist[255] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 255

#Test the case with no 1s
inlist = [0] * 8
assert binary_search(inlist) == -1
```

But it fails on this corner case

```
inlist = [0]*4
inlist[2] = 1
assert binary_search(inlist) == 2
```

What seems to be happening is that in the first stage everything goes as expected:

```
inList = [0,0,1,0]
upper = [1,0]
lower = [0,0]
```

However in the second stage mid, high and low all become 3 and

```
upper = [0]
lower = []
```

i.e. the 1 is missed.

I spent an hour in the debugger and modified the function to:

```
def binary_search(inList)
    low = 0
    high = len(inList) -1
    while low <= high:
        mid = low + (high - low) // 2
        if any(inList[low:mid]):    # <- this one
            high = mid - 1
        elif any(inList[mid + 1:high+1]): # <- this one
            low = mid + 1
        else:
            return mid
    return -1
```

This now passes all the tests above (and the weird cornner case) except for the all 0s test:

```
#Test the case with no 1s
inlist = [0] * 8
assert binary_search(inlist) == -1
```

I realise this is stupid, but I can't spot how to get the function to pass both tests.

Comment: You do realize that binary search is really only useful if you have an ordered list to begin with, right?

Comment: This is for a bespoke algorithm - it's better described as binary splitting. It doesn't require that the input is sorted - that would defeat the point of the algorithm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Fixing your program

You can 'fix' your program like so:

```
def binary_search(inList):
    low = 0
    high = len(inList)

    while low + 1 < high:
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        upper = inList[mid:high]
        lower = inList[low:mid]
        if any(lower):
            high = mid
        elif any(upper):
            low = mid
        else:
            # Neither side has a 1
            return -1
    return low
```

I changed the loop condition to "while low + 1 < high", the reassignment to "low = mid" (instead of low = mid + 1) and the result to "return low". This passes your tests.

The reason this works is that the way you have defined it, low, mid and high are better understood as bounds rather than indices:

```
  item 0 item 1 item 2 item 3 item 4 item 5 item 6 item 7 item 8
 |______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|______|
 0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
low                         mid                                high
```

When you split the list into two, you get two pieces like this:

```
  item 0 item 1 item 2 item 3 
 |______|______|______|______|
 0      1      2      3      4
low                         mid

  item 4 item 5 item 6 item 7 item 8
 |______|______|______|______|______|
 4      5      6      7      8      9
mid                                high
```

If you determine that the target value is in the upper half, it could be in *any* of those five indices. It doesn't make sense to set low = mid + 1, because that ignores the possibility that item #4 is the target item.

Eventually, this algorithm will narrow it down to a range of one item. Unlike your old algorithm, low will never equal high. So we stop when low + 1 == high, and the result is low. (Note that mid won't have been updated yet. low is the index we want.)

### Binary search

This is not what people mean when they talk about a binary search algorithm! Binary search is applied to a *sorted* list to find an element with a target value without having to compare every single element in the list. You can't apply binary search to an unsorted list. Think about it - there's just no way to know where to look - you have to check every item in the list until you find the target. Your algorithm is actually slower than a linear search, because it scans every item in the list multiple times!

Comment: I think I should have named it binary splitting. It's not a traditional search algorithm.

Comment: the reason for the lack of speed is using any(). Ideally I'd like to find a test which indicates the presence of the 1 for the whole sublist (like pooling blood samples and doing a single test for a disease on the pooled samples), but I'm stuck on that for the moment.

Comment: There's no way to do this if your input is an unsorted list of numbers and your goal is to guarantee to find the nonzero number without looking at every item in the list. But if you explain the context more, perhaps this isn't exactly what you need to do.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing is the context. My input is just a list of 0s and 1s and I need to find the 1. The algorithm I'm implementing can find the 1 in O(log(n)) comparisons.

Comment: What I'm saying is that *no* algorithm can find the 1 in a list of 0s and 1s in O(log(N)) time. Your algorithm depends on a mechanism (the 'all' function) to determine the presence of a 1 in a list of 0s in O(1) time, which is itself impossible. If that's what you're trying to do, you will not get anywhere. But maybe your input isn't actually a list of 1s and 0s but is some other representation of the same information. That's your only hope to achieve what you describe here. If the input is a list of 1s and 0s, you cannot succeed.

Comment: The way I'm implementing it, no - as I mentioned has already been pointed out to me. However, the algorithm can -theoretically - recover K 1s in a 'list' n long in O(klog(n)) comparisons. I am struggling looking for a better test than any(). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
while low <= high:
    mid = low + (high - low) // 2
    if any(inList[low:mid]):    # <- this one
        high = mid - 1
    elif any(inList[mid + 1:high+1]): # <- this one
        low = mid + 1
    else:
        return mid
```

Think about what happens when your list contains all `0`s. The `if` fails, since there are no `1`s in `inList` between `low` and `mid`. The `elif` also fails, as there are no `1`s between `mid` and `high`. Then there's an `else`, which is exactly what is executed now. Hence you don't get a `-1`.

Your `else` block is exactly the part of your code that is executed when there are no `1` in `inList`. Therefore, if you really want to handle the case of all `0`s, then you should make that block return `-1`

As a side-note though, I'm not sure why you would want to do anything resembling a binary search on an unsorted list.

Comment: This is a naive version of an algorithm for very sparse sets, it's used as a subroutine for a more sophisticated algorithm. Testing the better algorithm showed up that queer corner case.

Answer (score 1):

It's just not possible to solve your task with a binary search. See my comments at the bottom. However, you did almost implement a binary search correctly, so let's fix it and then talk about why it's not appropriate for this problem.

Here's a fixed version (of your original version) with comments. The overall structure is fine and these are just little off-by-one issues: for instance, you should set `low` to `mid` instead of `mid+1` or else you will miss the 1 if it was at `mid`.

```
def binary_search(inList):
    low = 0
    high = len(inList)

    while low < high - 1:  # Iterate while there are at least 2 elements
        mid = (low + high) // 2
        upper = inList[mid:high]
        lower = inList[low:mid]
        if any(lower):
            high = mid
        elif any(upper):
            low = mid  # mid was the first element in upper, so make sure to keep it
        if low == high - 1:
            # Only one element remains now, so it must be the 1
            return low
    return -1
```

However, as you noted, when you run any() you're scanning through the list, which negates the whole point of a binary search.

A binary search is a way to find something in a list without looking at every element in the list. How is that even possible? Only if the list is sorted. A binary search divides the list in half repeatedly, like you're doing, but only by looking at `mid` without examining `lower` and `upper`.

Comment: Well, this is for a group testing algorithm (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_testing). It's not a traditional binary search. The 1 indicates that the bin contains an item of interest - that's why I want to find it/ Ideally I'll come up with an O(1) way of testing upper and lower, but I'm using any() to get my hands dirty.

Comment: Ah, I see. Yeah, it totally makes sense if you'll be applying it to a different set of data where you can somehow test a subset in O(1) time, like weighing a set of coins.

Comment: Exactly! The best idea someone's suggested so far would be to use a long and just do upper != 0. But I don't know how to find the 1 like that.

Comment: Yeah, you could pack the bits into a long to make this particular example more efficient — but if it's just a toy problem on the way to solving something real, there's no point in doing that.